# Python, How to concatenate list as index?

Tags: python

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

b=[5,6,7,8]
```

Desired outcome from some sort of concatenation.

```
c=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

I need this to iterable as to concatenate a different b to c numerous times whilst retaining [[,,,],[,,,],[,,,],.......]

Comment: Just do `c = [a, b]`

Comment: If your lists aren't just `a` and `b`, you can also do it as a chain of `c = []` `c.append(list_you_want_to_append)` and do the `c.append()` for every list you want added.

Comment: with x=[1,2,3,4]   x.append([5,6,7,8]) results in [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7, 8]] i need [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

Comment: Thank you so much, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can append anything you want into a list. So for your example, we will start with an empty list `c` and append `a` and `b`. This method will continue to work for an arbitrary number of lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
c = []

# Now we append
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```

If we wanted to do this manually, or as a once only for fixed numbers of lists, we could just defined `c` as the list containing `a` and `b` like so:

```
c = [a, b]
```